# Kendo menu subitems are not rendering from client side

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, menu-items, kendo-menu

I am passing kendo MenuItem as `JSON` from server side to client side which are having `Mainmenu` and `SubMenu` options. `Mainmenu` is rendering properly but `SubMenu` are not rendering. let me explain with code;

below is my server side JSON data which i am sending to Client side:

[image]
and in my client side, data is rendering properly
[image]

but output is showing data for MainMenu items only not for SubMenu.
[image]
Below is my javascript code:

```
function KendoMenuItem(menuItem)
 {    
    jsObjectForkendoMenuItem = menuItem;    
}
function kendoMenu() {
    debugger;
   // alert(jsObjectForkendoMenuItem);
    $('#menu').kendoMenu({
        //orientation: "vertical",
        dataSource: [
            {
                text: "Add",
                value: "Add",
                items: jsObjectForkendoMenuItem                        
            },
        ],
        //select: onKendoMenuselect
    });
}
```

please let me know where i am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. the problem was I in `Items` was in capital letter.